# SaaS App data ingestion to DL/DWH - what include into NFR?

Tags: api, etl, saas, data-ingestion, data-lake

We are in the process for buying **SaaS solution** for busy sales operations. We want to ensure that we have ability to access our data and **ingest it into our analytics data lake** (some real-time). **I am looking for advice for what requirements should we have/prefer for vendors and their solutions?**

**APIs** - most vendors mention that they provide APIs for data access, however, **what features APIs need to have to be suitable for data ingestion into Analytics data lake?**. For example Salesforce has Bulk API, does this mean that if vendor only offers "lean APIs", they won't work for DL use case?

**Direct SQL Access** - **shall we **prefer** SaaS solutions that offer **single tenant DBs**** so that we could obtain direct SQL access?
**DB replica** - shall we expect that vendor provides a DB replica (if it's single tenant) and we use it as a data store for reporting. Obviously, that extra costs for us.

**Direct SQL Access via ODBC** - I also read that if SaaS app has multi-tenants, ODBC/JDBC drivers could be built to access DB data via SQL but with proper authorization to ensure data security? **Would this be a valid request/approach?**

**Staged tables** - shall we request the vendor to **stage their DB tables (as files) and load** to our (or theirs) data lake environment. This then would be a raw data source  analytics and data archive. My concern is incremental updates.

**Any other options we should consider/ look for in vendor solutions or request?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide your requirements (data lake architecture, data latency, etc.) to the vendors and get them to provide the solution that will work with their product.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, we have to do a public tender (government org.), meaning FR/NFR have to be specified in advance as it is used to rank vendors. That's why I need to really think that to add in NFR so it is useful, but not too limiting/impossible to meet.

Comment: But none of the items you have listed in your question are FRs/NFRs - they are solutions